# Avoiding kpathsea: Running mktexpk

Tags: texlive, pandoc, kpathsea

I'm running pandoc in a docker container based on the `FROM pandoc/ubuntu-latex` image, and it's working fine. However, each time it runs, I get the `kpathsea: Running mktexpk ...` step which seems to take extra time, every time I run that pandoc command.

Here's what the output looks like...

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 tcrm1095
mktexpk: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1+0/600; nonstopmode; input tcrm1095
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded base=mf)

(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/tcrm1095.mf
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/exbase.mf)
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/tcrm.mf
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txsymb.mf
 Ok (/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/exaccess.mf
 Ok) (/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txpseudo.mf
 Ok) (/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txaccent.mf
 Ok [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [27] [29])
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txgen.mf
 Ok [100] [109] [98] [99] [108])
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txsymbol.mf
 Ok [13] [18] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] [26] [28] [31] [32] [36] [39] [44]
[45] [46] [42] [47] [60] [61] [62] [77] [79] [87] [110] [91] [93] [94] [95]
[96] [126] [127] [128] [129] [130] [131] [132] [133] [134] [135] [136] [137]
[138] [139] [140] [141] [142] [143] [144] [145] [146] [147] [148] [149]
[150] [151] [152] [153] [154] [155] [156] [157] [158] [159] [160] [161]
[162] [163] [164] [165] [166] [167] [168] [169] [171] [172] [173] [174]
[175] [177] [176] [180] [181] [182] [183] [184] [187] [191] [214] [246])
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txromod.mf
 Ok [48] [49] [50] [51] [52] [53] [54] [55] [56] [57])
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txrsuper.mf
 Ok [185] [178] [179] [170] [186])
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txrfract.mf
 Ok [188] [189] [190]) ) ) )
(some charht values had to be adjusted by as much as 0.06952pt)
Font metrics written on tcrm1095.tfm.
Output written on tcrm1095.600gf (128 characters, 25592 bytes).
Transcript written on tcrm1095.log.
mktexpk: /root/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/tcrm1095.600pk: successfully generated.
```

In my `Dockerfile` I tried to run the same command kpathsea generates in the log output:

```
# create the fonts to save time each time a user will use them?
RUN mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 tcrm1095
```

which appears to run fine during the creation of the image, but it doesn't seem to change anything in the pandoc result -- kpathsea runs again.

How can I set up the docker image so that the existing `tcrm1095.tfm` files will be seen (or to avoid the `mktexpk` step each time)?

**Edit** I verified in a shell of the running docker container that `/root/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/tcrm1095.600pk` exists.

**Edit 2** A search in the docker container with a shell shows there are
`/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec/tcrm1095.tfm` and
`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec/tcrm1095.tfm`, yet pandoc is still generating them. Perhaps I'm missing an environment variable in the image?

Comment: it seems to create missing tfm-files, so you should add these tfm to your docker.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I added an edit to show they are indeed there. At least, the `/root/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/tcrm1095.600pk` is there. It's the result of the `RUN ...` command I added.

Comment: a file ending with `600pk` is not a tfm, tfm end with `.tfm`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought from the output that the `mktexpk` makes the `.tfm` files? The output log doesn't show anything about them specifically. Where do you think they are being created when pandoc runs? Where should they normally be so that `mktexpk` doesn't remake them?

Comment: well your log-files says `Font metrics written on tcrm1095.tfm`. And normally they should be in in some texmf in /fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec

Comment: @UlrikeFischer indeed, I see that they are in /opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec/tcrm1095.tfm and 
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec/tcrm1095.tfm -- is there an environment variable that's not set up perhaps so that texlive is finding them?

Comment: no idea, I'm not even sure that the tfm triggers the mktexpk call. it could also be a missing map file.

Answer (score 2):

I partially have an answer. My pandoc makefile was not using the *updated* docker image, with the `RUN` command to generate the `tfm` file. Once I fixed the makefile to use the newer docker image, the `kpathsea` command is not repeated.

However, I'm still not sure why the default image isn't finding the `.tfm` files installed in the `ec` (tlmgr) package, for example.

Comment: I have a similar problem with my Docker image FROM Python 3.10 with TexLive (via apt-get) plus libraries and my python scripts. Can you post your dockerfile as I don't really understand how you solved this issue?

Comment: Ah ... got it. It works! You're a genius!!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem but only with the `pdflatex` engine!.

When using `--pdf-engine=xelatex` or  `--pdf-engine=lualatex` it works fine.